# Abusing the downvote ability

Tags: discussion, down-votes, privileges

I feel that many users abuse the downvote feature and downvote genuinely researched questions/answers without any reason. I have noticed this in many posts and it has personally happened to me a few times. For example, this answer that I wrote: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4881030/1292819

I believe that my solution answered the OP's question perfectly but it still attracted 2 downvotes. This is especially demotivating and discouraging for new users to this site.

I propose increasing the rep requirement for downvotes to maybe around 1k to prevent its abuse

Comment: Some people (validly, in my opinion) downvote answers to questions that do not meet this site standards, because those answers encourage poor questions. Your answer there is a perfect example. I think you lack the experience and perspective to properly judge what is an "abuse" of downvoting.

Comment: Seconding the comment above, so you'll know it's not just one person's opinion. Additionally, your suggested solution probably wouldn't work, as it's mostly the people who have been around a long time (and have huge stonking rep scores) who down votes answers on clearly poorly done questions.

Comment: Also, I'd say the best way for you to deal with this is learn how to judge what is and isn't a good question for the site. It sucks that newly joining people aren't informed about this (this is a long standing issue that is surprisingly complicated), so you'll have to pick it up through observation. But you will need to be on-board with the fact that there are standards for questions that are enforced. If you're not willing to go along with that your going to spend a lot of time here being upset, and that not good for any of us.

Comment: By the way, and just FYI: in meta, upvotes/downvotes represent agreement/disagreement.

Comment: My mistake @peterwhy thanks for the catch